# Tested method call does not hit the service in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, testing, integration-testing

I am trying to test a service method that uses MapStruct as shown below:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {CategoryController.class, CategoryService.class, CategoryResponseMapperImpl.class})
class CategoryControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private CategoryController categoryController;

    @MockBean
    private CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

    @MockBean
    private CategoryService categoryService;

    @Spy
    // @SpyBean
    public CategoryResponseMapper categoryResponseMapper = new CategoryResponseMapperImpl();

    @Test
    void test_findById() throws Exception {
        LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDate.of(2022, 1, 1).atStartOfDay();

        Category category = new Category();
        category.setId(123L);
        category.setName("Category");
        category.setOrdinal(1);

        when(clock.instant()).thenReturn(dateTime.atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toInstant());
        when(categoryRepository.findById(any())).thenReturn(Optional.of(category));

        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api/v1/categories/{id}", 123L);
        MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(categoryController)
                .build()
                .perform(requestBuilder)
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.content().contentType("application/json"))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.content()
                        .string(
                                "{\"timestamp\":1640995200000,\"message\":\"Success\",\"data\":{\"id\":123,\"name\":\"Category\",\"ordinal\":1}}"));
    }
}
```

```
@GetMapping("/categories/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse<CategoryResponse>> findById(@PathVariable long id) {
    final CategoryResponse response = categoryService.findById(id);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(new ApiResponse<>(Instant.now(clock).toEpochMilli(), SUCCESS, response));
}
```

Although the test hits to the controller above, it does not hit the service method below and the response data returns as null:

```
private final CategoryRepository categoryRepository;
private final CategoryRequestMapper categoryRequestMapper;
private final CategoryResponseMapper categoryResponseMapper;

public CategoryResponse findById(Long id) {
    return categoryRepository.findById(id)
            .map(categoryResponseMapper::toDto)
            .orElseThrow(() -> {
                return new NoSuchElementFoundException(NOT_FOUND);
            });
}
```

So, where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

> Although the test hits to the controller above, it does not hit the
> service method below

Your test is currently written for testing of the controller and not the service. Because categoryService is mocked. Consider rewriting it. Like:

```
@Autowired
private CategoryService categoryService;

@MockBean
private CategoryRepository categoryRepository;
```

On the other hand if your goal is to test the controller you will need to add more mocked answers like this:

```
when(categoryService.findById(any())).thenReturn(categoryResponse);
```

Comment: Little addition: The problem is the entire test itself. If you want to test your controller you write a controller test, which you did. But in order for you to test your service, just write a service test. This is very important, as unit tests should be as modular as possible.

Comment: @Z-100 Right. But maybe this test normally would not need to go to service and I just assumed while testing. On the other hand, which approaches would you suggest for Unit and Integration testing with the new version of Spring? There are some new approaches and I would like to give a try to the useful ones.

Comment: @Mar-Z I get "Error creating bean with name 'categoryController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'categoryService': Uns..." error.

Comment: @fredrick Normally a controller just has methods, which then call another service for the logic. (For modularity). This that one doesn't really need to test a controller with a unit test, thus making your test sort of irrelevant => Instead test your service, which has the actual logic inside of it.. Integrationtests on the other hand just call your endpoints and tests the entire system at once, obviously they then also test the controllers.

Comment: Actually I meant Integration Test and what would you suggest to write integration Test (of course from Controller). Maybe the new approaches are better without involving in memory database, etc. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try the test like this:

```java
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@SpringBootTest
class CategoryControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    private CategoryService categoryService;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void test_findById() throws Exception {
        // Arrange
        LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDate.of(2022, 1, 1).atStartOfDay();

        final long categoryId = 123L;
        Category category = new Category();
        category.setId(categoryId);
        category.setName("Category");
        category.setOrdinal(1);

        when(clock.instant()).thenReturn(dateTime.atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toInstant());
        when(categoryService.findById(categoryId)).thenReturn(Optional.of(category));

        // Act & assert
        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/v1/categories/{id}", categoryId))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json"))
                .andExpect(content().string("{\"timestamp\":1640995200000,\"message\":\"Success\",\"data\":{\"id\":123,\"name\":\"Category\",\"ordinal\":1}}"));
    }

}
```

With this setup, you let Spring basically create the standard application context. The `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` annotation allows you to use the `MockMvc` object to make requests against your controllers.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I could just tried it. But gives "FATAL: password authentication failed for user "${DB_USERNAME}" and I do not know how the test tries to access to the database without hitting to the service (still not hit to the service method). I also set static values in my application properties, not solved. I will try to add env variable to Intellij, but dont think it wll be useful. Any idea?

Comment: You can also share a best practices and proper examples tutorial for unit and integration testing in Spring Boot. I will also check them.

Comment: It also does not hit even the Test method. Any idea?